# Rao-Blackwellization in Black Box VI

Tags: monte-carlo, conditional-expectation, notation, rao-blackwell, variational

In the paper, ["*Black Box Variational Inference,*"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0118.pdf) by Ranganath et al. (2013), the authors derive a Rao-Blackwellized estimator of the gradient of the evidence lower bound with respect to a single variational parameter $\lambda_i$. Notation:

- $q(z | \lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n q(z_i | \lambda_i)$ is the factorized variational approximation.
- $q_{(i)}$ is "the distribution of variables in the model that depend on the $i$'th variable, i.e. the Markov blanket of $z_i$."
- $p_i(x, z_{(i)})$ is the product of the terms in the joint that depend on those variables.

Then by their derivation,

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\lambda_i} \mathcal{L} = E_{q_{(i)}} \left[\nabla_{\lambda_i} \log q(z_i | \lambda_i)(\log p_i(x, z_{(i)}) - \log q(z_i | \lambda_i)) \right].
\end{equation}
With samples $z_s \sim q_{(i)}(z | \lambda)$, they then propose to estimate the above via Monte Carlo.
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\lambda_i}\mathcal{L} \approx \frac{1}{S}\sum_{s=1}^S \nabla_{\lambda_i} \log q_i(z_s | \lambda_i)(\log p_i(x, z_s) - \log q_i(z_s | \lambda_i)).
\end{equation}
My question is: is it not an abuse of notation to write $q_i(z_s | \lambda_i)$, since $z_s$ is vector-valued (one entry for each R.V. in the Markov blanket) and $q_i$ is properly a conditional distribution of a univariate random variable?

In that case, what are we supposed to read for $q_i(z_s | \lambda_i)$?

To be even more pedantic, the Markov blanket of an R.V. doesn't include the R.V. itself, right? So a sample $z_s$ doesn't contain an entry corresponding to variable $i$, so the conditional is undefined.

So if the above is correct, then we are making two leaps:

- By Markov blanket the authors refer to the classical notion of Markov blanket, plus the RV itself.
- There is implicit indexing into $z_s$ going on when we write $q_i(z_s | \lambda_i)$ (should be $q_i(z_{si} | \lambda_i))$.

Answer (score 0):

> By Markov blanket the authors refer to the classical notion of Markov
> blanket, plus the RV itself.

Yes.

> There is implicit indexing into $z_s$ going on when we write $q_i(z_s
> > | \lambda_i)$ (should be $q_i(z_{si} | \lambda_i))$.

Yes.

Very pedantic indeed.